# Extjs store reader fully qualified json property names

Tags: json, extjs

Using Extjs 3+ and server side is sending back the following JSON:

```
{"com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.QueryResponse": {"com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.successful":true,"com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.count":1,"com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.elements":{"com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.id":123,"com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.name":"Mars","com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.fromTimeStamp":"2010-07-08T16:38:00.478+02:00","com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.createTimeStamp":"2010-07-08T16:38:00.478+02:00","com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.updateTimeStamp":"2010-10-25T15:02:09.446+02:00","com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.type":{"com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.id":1,"com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.name":"{http:\/\/www.klistret.com\/cmdb\/ci\/element\/logical\/collection}Environment","com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.fromTimeStamp":"2009-08-05T11:20:12.471+02:00","com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.createTimeStamp":"2009-08-05T11:20:12.471+02:00","com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.updateTimeStamp":"2009-08-05T11:20:12.471+02:00"},"com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.configuration":{"@www.w3.org.2001.XMLSchema-instance.type":"com.klistret.cmdb.ci.element.logical.collection:Environment","@Watermark":"past","com.klistret.cmdb.ci.commons.Name":"Mars"}}}}
```

The reader is setup up as follows:

```
    var reader = new CMDB.JsonReader(
            {
            totalProperty       : 'com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.count',
                successProperty     : 'com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.successful',
                idProperty          : 'com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.id',
                root                : 'com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.elements'
            }, 
            [
            {name: 'Id',   mapping: 'com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.id'},
                {name: 'Name', mapping: 'com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.name'}
            ]
        );
```

The store as:

```
    var ds = new Ext.data.Store({
            proxy      : new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
                url    : 'http://sadbmatrix2:55167/CMDB/resteasy/element'
            }),

            reader     : reader 
        });
```

The reader extends the Ext.data.JsonReader as explained by http://erichauser.net/2007/11/07/more-wcf-json-and-extjs/ to remove the "com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.QueryResponse" start node in the JSON returned from the server.

The extended reader never gets called.  Assuming the problem is due to has fully qualified property names in the JSON object returned (ie. "com.klistret.cmdb.ci.pojo.name" rather than just "name").

Anybody use gotten around this?

Comment: Are you sure you're using ScriptTagProxy correctly?  Meaning - is the server properly wrapping that JSON in a callback function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean my the "server" wrapping a callback function?  Haven't used the ScriptTagProxy before but the example (http://www.sencha.com/forum/topics-browse-remote.php) from Sencha just sends JSON data.  Main problem is after the doRequest call there is a failure either in the callback funtion (which is dynamically interlaced into the window object and tuff to read) or somewhere else.

Comment: var tProxy = new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
            url    : 'http://sadbmatrix2:55167/CMDB/resteasy/element',
            params : {
             start    : 0,
          limit    : 20,
          expressions : expressions[0]
            }
        });
        
var options = {
     params   :  {
         start    : 0,
         limit    : 20,
         expressions : expressions[0]
        }
    };
         
tProxy.request(Ext.data.Api.actions['read'], null, options.params, null, null, null, tProxy, options);

Ends up the the handleFailure after the timeout Extjs traps (trans.callback is null)

Comment: Got ya.  When the callback is sent the JSON is wrapped by the server.  Sorry.  Totally missed that concept in ScriptTagProxy....not something usable then....still don't see how the actual request is made?  The doRequest methods ends and wham the request is made...an event?

Comment: TimDev...."answer" question so I can mark you for points...you pointed me in the right direction....thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We worked it out (well, mostly Matthew did) in the comments:

ScriptTagProxy needs the server to wrap the JSON data in a function call so that your local code can get access to it.

Instead of the server emitting something like:

```
{here:'is data}
```

it needs to return

```
somefunc("{here:'is data'}");
```

That way, your client-side implementaiton of `somefunc()` is called and can process the returned data.